# RegEx in PHP: Matching a pattern outside of non-escaped quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a method to lift certain data out of an SQL query string, and I need to regex match any word inside of curly braces ONLY when it appears *outside* of single-quotes.  I also need it to factor in the possibility of escaped (preceded by backslash) quotes, as well as escaped backslashes.

In the following examples, I need the regex to match {FOO} and not {BAR}:

```
blah blah {FOO} blah 'I\'m typing {BAR} here with an escaped backslash \\'
blah blah {FOO} 'Three backslashes {BAR} and an escaped quote \\\\\\\' here {BAR}'
```

I'm using preg_match in PHP to get the word in the braces ("FOO", in this case).  Here's the regex string I have so far:

```
$regex = '/' .
    // Match the word in braces
    '\{(\w+)\}' .
    // Only if it is followed by an even number of single-quotes
    '(?=(?:[^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)' .
    // The end
    '/';
```

My logic is that, since the only thing I'm parsing is a legal SQL string (besides the brace-thing I added), if a set of braces is followed by an *even* number of non-escaped quotes, then it must be outside of quotes.

The regex I provided is 100% successful EXCEPT for taking escaped quotes into consideration.  I just need to make sure there is no odd number of backslashes before a quote match, but for the life of me I can't seem to convey this in RegEx.  Any takers?

Comment: This is one of those times when using a regex just means you now have two problems. A simple state-machine would be much easier to do.

Comment: I concur! For parsing a language, just avoid using regexes. I love these, but they are not a good fit for this task.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but this case is a bit different.  I don't need to parse through the language -- I *only* need to pull out text in braces, and only on one line at a time.  Exactly what RegEx was made for.  It would be a shame to have to run each line through a state machine when a single, far less expensive preg_match() call could do the trick.

Comment: What makes you think that preg_match will be less expensive?

Comment: The strings, though single SQL queries, can still be arbitrarily large.  Code cleanliness aside, I would expect the natively-supported preg engine to offer greater consistency and speed than a php-interpreted function to iterate through each character while collecting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to deal with escaped quotes and backslashes is to consume them in matched pairs.

```
(?=(?:(?:(?:[^\'\\]++|\\.)*+\'){2})*+(?:[^\'\\]++|\\.)*+$)
```

In other words, as you scan for the next quote, you skip any pair of characters that starts with a backslash. That takes care of both escaped quotes and escaped backslashes.  This lookahead will allow escaped characters outside of quoted sections, which probably isn't necessary, but it probably won't hurt either.

p.s., Notice the liberal use of possessive quantifiers (`*+` and `++`); without those you could have performance problems, especially if the target strings are large.  Also, if the strings can contain line breaks, you may need to do the matching in DOTALL mode (aka, "singleline" or "/s" mode).

However, I agree with mmyers: if you're trying to parse SQL, you *will* run into problems that regexes can't handle at all.  Of all the things that regexes are bad at, SQL is one of the worst.

Comment: Ingenious work, Alan!  Thanks very much -- this is exactly what I was looking for.  As I mentioned in reply to mmyers, though, I'm definitely not trying to parse the SQL language with this.  All I needed was to lift out those bracketed items, with no further processing.  For arbitrary length strings, preg_match is definitely the cleaner, and most likely less expensive, method.

Comment: Can someone put this into a regex101.com example to share a working version - I've tried it and don't see it working? https://regex101.com/r/GBIXTq/1

Answer (score 0):

Simply, and perhaps naively, str_replace out all your double backslashes.  Then str_replace out escaped single quotes.  At that point it's relatively simple to find matches that are not between single quotes (using your existing regex, for example).

Comment: Unfortunately with this solution, you need to replace those instances with a character(s) that you can be positive won't appear in the rest of your string.  In this case, I can make no such assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regular expressions for this, I would do it in two steps:

1. Separate the *strings* from the *non-strings* with `preg_split`:

   ```
   $re = "('(?:[^\\\\']+|\\\\(\\\\\\\\)*.)*')";
   $parts = preg_split('/'.$re.'/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
   ```
2. Replace the whatever in the *strings*:

   ```
   foreach ($parts as $key => $val) {
       if (preg_match('/^'.$re.'$/', $val)) {
           $parts[$key] = preg_replace('/\{([^}]*)}/', '$1', $val);
       }
   }
   ```

But a real parser would probably be better as this approach is not that efficient.